# Не выкладывается пост в одноклассники

Tags: python, requests, cookie, одноклассники

Пытаюсь написать программу на Python, которая будет проходить аутентификацию на сайте https://ok.ru и выкладывать заданный, пост на страницу пользователя. C аутентификацией все хорошо, а вот выложить пост не получается. Заранее спасибо!

```py
import requests
import pickle


# данные для авторизации
login_data = {
    'st.email': '********',
    'st.password': '*********'
}

# отправляем POST-запрос для авторизации
response = requests.post('https://www.ok.ru/dk?cmd=AnonymLogin&st.cmd=anonymLogin', data=login_data)

# сохраняем Cookies в файл
cookies = response.cookies
with open('cookies.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(cookies, f)

# загружаем Cookies из файла
with open('cookies.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    cookies = pickle.load(f)

# создаем сессию
session = requests.Session()

payload = {
    'st.cmd': 'postingForm',
    'st.layer.cmd': 'PublishPostLayer',
    'st.postingForm': 'true',
    'st.hasAttach': '0',
    'st.attachmentIndex': '-1',
    'st.attachmentType': '',
    'st.shareBoxPlaceholder': 'Что у вас нового?',
    'st._aid': 'PublishPostLayer_buttonPublish',
    'st._av': '1',
    'st._sn': '1',
    'st._surl': '/profile/575417218737',
    'st._t': '0',
    'st.status': 'Hello, world!'  # Текст поста
}

post_requests = session.post('https://www.ok.ru/dk?cmd=PostingForm&st.cmd=postForm', data=payload, cookies=cookies)



if post_requests.status_code == 200:
    print('Пост успешно опубликован в профиле!')
else:
    print('Ошибка при публикации поста в профиле')
```

Comment: Сессию нужно создавать в самом начале и уже после неё авторизовываться

Comment: A вы уверенны, что прошли аутентификацию? если нет ошибок, не значить, что аутентификация пройдена успешна.